# Crontab issues with PHP and image creation

Tags: php, image, cron

**The context:**
I wrote a script which downloads an image from a server, sets white colour to transparent, and saves the image in root folder. It also saves a copy of the image in a separate folder "images" with date and time in its name.

Because I don't exactly know when the image is refreshed, I keep hashes of images in a database alongside with the date of creation and file name.

**The problem:**
I want the script to run automatically every 5 minutes, so I created a crontab on my server (Ubuntu Server 12.04). Crontab does execute the script every 5 minutes, however it only adds new records to the database without saving the actual images. When I try and run the script manually trough the console or a web browser it works as it should: saves the images and updates the database records.

**Crontab** (in case there's something wrong with it):

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 -f /var/www/radar.php > /var/www/logPHP.log 2>&1
```

**PHP code:**

```
include 'mysql.php';

$im = imagecreatefromgif("image_url");
$hash = hash_file('md5', "image_url");

$day = date("j");
$month = date("n");
$year = date("Y");
$hour = date("G");
$minute = date("i");

$file = 'image' . $day . '-' . $month . '-' . $year . '_' . $hour . '_' . $minute . '.gif';

echo "Hash: " . $hash . "<br />";
echo "Start: " . date("H:i:s") . "<br />";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE hash = '$hash' LIMIT 1");
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num == 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO pictures (year, month, day, hour, minute, hash, file) VALUES ('$year', '$month', '$year', '$hour', '$minute', '$hash', '$file')");

    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor(799, 599);
    imagecopy($dest, $im, 0, 0, 10, 49, 799, 599);

    $color = imagecolorexact($dest, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($dest, $color);

    imagegif($dest, './image.gif');
    imagegif($dest, './images/' . $file);
    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
echo "End: " . date("H:i:s");
?>
<br /><img src="./image.gif" />
```

**Edit:**
Now I added another line to crontab which download image with wget and saves it into specific folder. Image is downloaded without a problem. I also edited php file to use downloaded image but problem doesn't go away. No images are created.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, CLI PHP uses a different ini file than the one associated with your web server.  If this is your case too, then calls to include() may well be polling through completely different include_path(s) hence cannot find mysql.php

Turn error reporting on for this page and see if that shows up the error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: I get nothing else than missing favicon. At least not in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0):

Well try your crontab line through any other folder from script folder ( like home folder ).

```
/usr/bin/php5 -f /var/www/radar.php
```

If script running in this case. Then it can be possible crontab is not running for your user at all. Then configure cron logs or check in syslog for any information.

Comment: The script is run by crontab, database gets updated but images are not created.

Comment: Then obviously Wrong Path Or User permission would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your crontab file misses the user name who should be running the script. Try something like that :

```
*/5 * * * * www-data /usr/bin/php5 -f /var/www/radar.php > /var/www/logPHP.log 2>&1
```

Your `/var/log/syslog` should have complained about crond error like `missing username`.

Good luck for you project.

Comment: And I tried with www-data, my username, root. I even tried with myusername:www-data and www-data:www-data.